# How to paste the data in specific row in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new using VBA and I'm creating a simple project to enhance my knowledge in VBA programming.

Now I have 2 sheets in my excel, `Sample1` and `Sample2`, of course `Sample1` is my master page now I want to get specific column data in `Sample2` and paste it to `Sample1`.  I already achieved this. Now my problem is I want to paste it to specific row in `Sample1` because my problem when I copy a data from `Sample2` and paste to `Sample1` the data will show at the bottom.

This is my code, as you can see I want my project be dynamic.

`Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long`

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sample2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
    Worksheets("Sample2").Cells(i, 5).Copy
    erow = Worksheets("Sample1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sample2").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sample1").Cells(erow + 1, 1)
    Worksheets("Sample2").Cells(i, 7).Copy
    Worksheets("Sample2").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sample1").Cells(erow + 1, 2)
Next i
```

What I want is when I copy a data from `Sample2` to `Sample1` it will paste it to specific column for eg. `A5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your references to `Rows.Count` are not fully qualified, so it is looking at the ActiveWorkbook instead of the one you want.

For the second one, reference the other worksheet:

```
erow = Worksheets("Sample1").Cells(Worksheets("Sample1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

In addition, you may want to do a similar thing with the first one:

```
lastrow = Worksheets("Sample2").Cells(Worksheets("Sample2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Same problem, What I want is when I copy data from `Sample2`  and paste to `Sample1`  I want the data paste to specific row.

Comment: What do You mean with "specific row"? You mean specified by You just before pasting? For example using InputBox at the beginning of every loop iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Your lastrow column should be 5 not 1:
lastrow = Worksheets("Sample2").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)